# How to add a where clause when returning a list in a view Mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it possible to add a where clause in the view rather than the controller as I don't want to change the retrieval of information in the controller. I currently am retrieving a list of restaurants but want to only show restaurants where the logged in users email is the same as the restaurants email.

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RestaurantName)
            </th>             
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.County)
            </th>               
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RestaurantType)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RestaurantName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
                </td>                    
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RestaurantType)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.RestaurantID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.RestaurantID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RestaurantID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Best to keep logic out of the view.. so the best option would probably be to  create a viewmodel

Comment: can you share Model's code?

Comment: The proper place to do this in the controller. The view is responsible for displaying the data passed to it. So 1) don't retrieve data you don't need in the controller and 2) don't pass data to the controller you don't intend to display.

Comment: Your goal is a little confusing.. in your controller you are retrieving a list of restaurants to send to the view.. but in the view you want to filter that list even more? sounds like you might want to create another action and view possibly.. only retrieve the information that you definitely want to display to the user in the controller

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid The list of restaurants I am retrieving is all the restaurants in the Restaurant tbl but I only want to show the restaurants that the restaurant owner owns. (This in my case will be the email address of the logged in user)

Comment: @Smac I understand, so non-logged in users will be able to see the entire table?

Comment: Why don't you want to do it in the controller? You should certainly not do this in the view, view is only responsible for presentation and this is not presentation it is infact logic so should go either in controller (or service layer if large app)

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Yes thats basically it, they will be the customers but for the restaurant owner I only want to display their own restaurant if they have one and not the full table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't want to change the logic for retrieving the list, you could use a ViewModel with a List property, returning the specified list using the Getter.

```
public List<Restaurant> MyRestaurants 
{
    get { return Restaurants.Where(x => x.RestaurantEmail == UserEmail); }
}
```